# How to store uploaded files with non-ASCII filename?

Tags: php, windows, apache, url, file-upload

I cannot pass a **UTF-8** filename to [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/function.move-uploaded-file.php) as it gets converted bytewise, resulting in a faulty name in the file system. For example:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], '\upload\é.jpg');
```

creates *xa9.jpg* in the upload directory.

While the Windows API supports **UTF-16**, passing such filename (e.g., [`iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', 'é')`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.iconv.php)) to `move_uploaded_file()` results in an error.

It would be reasonable to **percent-encode** all special characters, and I definitely should do the same with the URIs, according to [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). But when I use percent-encoded URIs, Apache gives a 404 error, as it decodes the URL and can't find anything by that name.

For example: `<img src="/upload/%C3%A9.jpg" />` gives the Apache error:

> File does not exist: […]/upload/\xc3\xa9.jpg.

What would be the proper solution? If I rename the file in Windows (*é.jpg*), the encoded HTML URI (*%C3%A9.jpg*) works as expected.

---

Some info on the subject: http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/filesystem-encoding-and-php

Comment: Base64 encode the filename provided by the client and use that as the local filename?

Comment: Do you need to maintain the uploaded file name at all?  Can you just assign a new name?

Comment: @Aerik I do, that's the point of the question! In later projects I will definitely use auto-generated filenames with strict ASCII rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing `iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1250', $_FILES['userfile']['name'])` to `move_uploaded_file()`, *as opposed to using UTF-16*, and saving the filename for HTML as `rawurlencode($_FILES['userfile']['name'])` works.

If this filename is stored in a database, any file request should refer to `iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1250', rawurldecode($filename))`.

I use Windows-1250 charater set as this is the default on my system.

Additional info on MSDN:

- [Character Sets Used in File Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (See: [Code Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
- [File and Directory Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#file_and_directory_names) (Naming Conventions)